# Programmatically created custom view with button target

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, swift, uiview

I'm having an custom *UIView* subclass which has some *UIButtons* appended. For every button there is an target action defined on the *UIViewController* which is including the custom *UIView*.

Somehow the *TouchUpInside* event is never being caught within the custom view including ViewController. Since UIViews are part of the *UIResponderChain* I wonder why events are not being fired? Does it make any sense to delegate the target action or should this be done another way?

**Custom UIView Subclass: CustomView**

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 100.0, 100.0))
button.addTarget(self.delegate, action: "buttonTapped:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

**ViewController**

```
// Include the custom view
let customView = CustomView()
customView.delegate = self
self.view.addSubview(customView)
...

func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject!) {
    // Doesn't get called
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I was missing to declare the frame rect for the buttons - so buttons are being displayed, but they're indeed not clickable.

Answer (score 1):

Do you set `userInteractionEnabled` to `YES` on your custom view? It's `NO` by default on views that are not descended from `UIResponder` (mostly buttons).

If a view's `userInteractionEnabled = NO`, it will ignore touch events.

Answer (score 0):

I assume self.delegate is nil when you adding target...
Few solutions:

- initialise custom view with delegate (create custom function initWithFrame:delegate)
- override setDelegate function for custom view, and add target to button there;
- make button variable public, and manually add target to it in your external class